# How do I ensure my uiview is always a square?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm writing a uiview subclass that must be displayed in a square frame for it to format correctly.

How do i write the api so that consumers can only request a square, and any changes to its frame happen in proportion?

Or is it enough to let the consumer know in documentation that this view will only work with square frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to override the `setFrame:` method in your custom view class:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (frame.size.width != frame.size.height) {
         // Update this logic to suit your needs
         frame.size.height = frame.size.width;
    }

    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

Comment: THanks. Is not letting the user set frame precisely considered bad design?

Comment: No, but not telling them when they do something wrong and you auto change it can be considered bad implementation.

Comment: @JasonC.Howlin You asked how to make a view square and now you are questioning your design? Whether this is valid or not depends on how it will be used. Only you can decide if your need is bad or not. Again, this is only one option. Another is to let the frame be anything but render the content to be square. Decide if the square content should be centered in the frame or pinned to one of the corners.

Comment: Right thats what i am afraid of. So log a warning but what else? I feel like throwing an exception for a frame size is unusual too.

Comment: Your needs are unclear. It's your app, you are writing the code. Who is going to see the warning? Certainly not the users of your app. Is this check only being done during development?

Comment: Yes im questioning my design -- thats why I'm asking a question on SO! I like the idea of pinning vs. resizing the frame on them. thanks. There are other developers that will be using the class in various apps.

Answer (score -1):

Just set the frame as a rectangle

```
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(<#CGFloat x#>, <#CGFloat y#>, <#CGFloat width#>, <#CGFloat height#>)
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)]
```

Or any multiply thereof